# How to import a dataset that already has time data in R and stop R from converting that time data into integers

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to import a dataset in **R**, which has time data and looks like this.

[image: this is original file with time data]

But, when I try to assign it to *time series*, the *time* data is being converted to integers, like this:

```
# AEP_hourly is the original file name
> names(AEP_hourly)
[1] "Datetime" "AEP_MW"
> hourly_ts <- ts(AEP_hourly)
```

[image: The time data being converted to numeric]

How do I stop this and tell **R** that it is time data in first column.

Comment: What function are you using to load the csv file? I have used `read.csv` and it works fine.

Comment: `> library(readr)
> AEP_hourly <- read_csv("AEP_hourly.csv")`

Comment: Okay, why do you need to show them as datetime? I mean, for what do you need `hourly_ts`? For the plot?

Answer (score 1):

Buddy you are converting datetime column into ts().
therefore it is giving result like this.convert only aep column

your code

```
       hour_data <- ts(hourly[,c('time','AEP_MW')])
```

instead of above code write like this

```
       hour_data <- ts(hourly$AEP_MW)
```

Comment: as.POSIXCT(hourly$Datetime)
Error in as.POSIXCT(hourly$Datetime) : 
  could not find function "as.POSIXCT"


That is the error message.

Comment: >hourly <- AEP_hourly
> as.date(hourly$Datetime)
Error in as.date(hourly$Datetime) : could not find function "as.date"
> as.POSIXCT(hourly$Datetime)
Error in as.POSIXCT(hourly$Datetime) : 
  could not find function "as.POSIXCT"



that is what i got.

Comment: The function is `as.POSIXct`, with the lowercase `ct`

Comment: @Naveen: Yes its as.POSIXct(), and share your code and error message.

Comment: I've already shared my error message, which is second comment to the answer. see the answer, it had 'POSIXCT' with capital 'CT', which led me to me error.
Thanks.

Comment: (AEP_hourly is the original file' name) 
`> names(AEP_hourly) 
[1] "Datetime" "AEP_MW" 
> hourly <- AEP_hourly 
> hourly$time <- as.POSIXct(hourly$Datetime) 
> names(hourly) 
[1] "Datetime" "AEP_MW" "time" 
> hour_data <- ts(hourly[,c('time','AEP_MW')])`

check this picture, that column is still numeric.
drive.google.com/open?id=1VntT55i_yWkCSJJNO-wNik_YPIJChNHi

Comment: I think you are converting both datetime and aep to ts(), Convert only aep column ts(dataframe$aep) and then do forecast.

Comment: When you try to convert date into ts() it will convert into above string as in datetime column.

Comment: Yep, you are converting time to ts() as your code in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need the `time` to be included int `ts` object. Using the following:

```
hour_data <- ts(hourly[,c('AEP_MW')])
```

will give an output similar to this:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 11 
Frequency = 1 
      AEP_MW
 [1,]  13478
 [2,]  12865
 [3,]  12577
 [4,]  12517
 [5,]  12670
 [6,]  13038
 [7,]  13692
 [8,]  14297
 [9,]  14719
[10,]  14941
[11,]  15184
```

Now, if you `plot(hour_data)` this, you would get this:

[image]

But I guess you desire to show the `time` in the x-axis. You may do so as follows:

```
plot(hour_data, xaxt = "n", ylab="AEP_MW")
axis(1, at=rownames(hourly), labels=hourly$Datetime)
```

Which will give you this plot:

[image]

Hope this helps.